# Authorizing partial web methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, authorization

I am using ASMX web services (not WCF) and I implemented simple HTTP module for Basic Authentication.
Everything works fine for authorizing files (web.config deny/allow) and User.IsInRole is also filled.

However, I want to authorize partial web methods. For this purpose, I found only PrincipalPermission.Demand atributes. However, it allways throws an exception although I passed valid login credentials.

Web config:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="AuthenticationModule" type="AuthenticationModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
        <authentication mode="None"/>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Client:

```
CommonService.CommonServices service = new CommonService.CommonServices();
               service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pass);
                service.PreAuthenticate = true;
                service.HelloWorldForEveryone();
```

It throws:

```
Unhandled exception: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Serv
ices.Protocols.SoapException: 
   v System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission.ThrowSecurityException()
   v System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission.Demand()
   v System.Security.PermissionSet.DemandNonCAS()
   v WSAutentization.CommonServices.HelloWorldForEveryone() in CommonServices.asmx.cs:řádek 30
   v System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClien
tMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall
)
   v System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodNa
me, Object[] parameters)
   v Console.CommonService.CommonServices.HelloWorldForEveryone() v d:\TMP\WSAut
entization\Console\Web References\CommonService\Reference.cs:řádek 93
   v Console.Program.Main(String[] args) v d:\TMP\WSAutentization\Console\Progra
m.cs:line 35
```

Is there another way how to authorize partial web methods?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`PrincipalPermission` is checked against `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. 
I don't see code in your authentication module, but I had the same problems and the solution was to set

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
```